# how to generate uniform random binary numbers to calculate hamming distance pairwise in C++?

Tags: c++, binary

I want to generate 100 uniform random 8-bits binary numbers like these:

01111010, 11011010, 11100010, 10111010, ...

so that i can calculate the hamming distance pairwise.

I found many duplicate questions, but there is no solution, except negative points!!!!!

I also found this link : http://www.psychocodes.in/c-program-to-calculate-hamming-distance-of-two-binary-strings.html

But it doesn't generate the numbers automatically! I want to generate the binary form of the numbers without taking inputs from user.

I know there are ways to calculate hamming distance of two integers, but note that I want to have binary forms.

Comment: The C++ standard library have a very nice [selection of PRNG classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniform_int_distribution` from standard library. E.g,

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>

int main(){
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 eng(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 255);
  std::vector<std::uint8_t> nums(100);
  for (auto& i: nums) {
    i = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(distr(eng));
  }  
}
```

Now vector `nums` has 100 elements of 8 bit numbers.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't allow 'uint8_t' in 'uniform_int_distribution' !

Comment: @NicolBolas except the [documentation is quite clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) they will have to use `unsigned short` and cast down. Annoying but still not an issue. Honestly because the limit is 0 - 255 I'd just let it use the default `int` and not care, the cast won't cost anything.